# Half-normal probability plot

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, approximation, order-statistics

To construct the half-normal probability plot, plot the absolute values in a certain statistical diagnostic (residual, leverage, Cook distance and others) versus $z_i$ where:

$\displaystyle z_{i}  = \Phi^{-1} \left(\frac{k + n - \frac{1}{8}}{2n +\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

$\therefore$ Applied Linear Statistical Models, (Kutner,Nachtsheim,Neter & Li, 2005) Fifth Edition, Pag 596

or

$\displaystyle z_{i} = \Phi^{-1} \left(\frac{k + n + \frac{1}{2}}{2n +\frac{9}{8}}\right)$

$\therefore$ Generalized Linear Models, (P. McCullagh & J.A. Nelder, 1989) Second Edition,  Pag 407

where  $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

$k$ is the  $k$-th ordered absolute residual

$n$ is the sample size

I could not locate the mathematical justification for the difference of the $z_i$, and more importantly I don't have any intuition about where it comes from.

Any help? Could you please guide me?

Comment: What $n$ and $k$ stand for here?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, Thanks. $k$ is the  $kth$ ordered absolute residual and $n$ is the sample size

Comment: @Will, Sorry, I wrote in Portuguese, means where.

Comment: Oh like donde in Spanish, no worries

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Some help?

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to a PP plot, and not to a QQ plot?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different "finite-sample/discrete sample" corrections, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot#Heuristics) for the Normal probability plot (not the half normal).

Looking at Kutner *et al.* book, I see that they "link" their Half-normal probability plot formula to the following formula for the **Normal PP**:

$$\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{k-0.375}{n+0.25}\right)$$

This, I read, is the formula used in the book "**Blom, G. (1958), Statistical estimates and transformed beta variables**, New York: John Wiley and Sons", and it is also the one used in the software program **Minitab**.

So I would suggest to contact Minitab people (that also has a half-normal PP feature) and ask them "what formula did you use for the half-normal plot, and where did you get it?"

I also see that **Cullagh & Nelder** use the same as above expression for the Normal plot, while offering the different expression for the half-normal plot.... Nelder has passed, but [Peter McCullagh is still active](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/) so one could always contact him directly for advice,